# Why am I getting TableNotEnabledException when creating a graph using ConfiguredGraphFactory in JanusGraph with HBase?

Tags: hbase, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I tried to create a new graph using `ConfiguredGraphFactory` by running the following in the gremlin shell. (These steps are adapted from [this part of the JanusGraph documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/configured-graph-factory/#template-configuration).)

```groovy
map = new HashMap<String, Object>
map.put("storage.backend","hbase")
map.put("storage.hostname","127.0.0.1")
ConfiguredGraphFactory.createTemplateConfiguration(new MapConfiguration(map));
ConfiguredGraphFactory.create("graph1")
```

When I run the last line, I get an error in the client stating that `graph1` is disabled, and I see a `TableNotEnabledException` in the gremlin server log.

I seem to be able to get around the issue by manually enabling the `graph1` table in HBase, but this is inconvenient. Additionally, JanusGraph doesn't seem to be creating the traversal binding for `graph1`—I get an error when I try to use `graph1_traversal`.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was able to fix both of the issues mentioned by changing the `channelizer` in my gremlin server configuration from `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer` to `org.janusgraph.channelizers.JanusGraphWebSocketChannelizer`.

That this change is necessary is documented at [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/basics/multi-node/#dynamic-graph-and-traversal-bindings).